# What's the best way to update a Python application you've converted to a windows application

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

So I'm working on an application that's going to need to be updated every month or two.

If I use Pyinstaller or Py2Exe to convert it to an windows executable , would there be any way to push updates that application remotely?